# UIImagePickerController multiple select

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `UIImagePickerController` for get photos from the device and I want to know if there is any way to select *multiple photos* with this mechanism ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to look at [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController). You can select multiple images with that.

Answer (score 16):

Sadly not, the picker is only for single images or videos. You will need to create your own to simulate the normal photo album.

Comment: It's so weird that apple doesn't add this api to the UIKiT framework since this option is available in the browser. I believe we have to submit the feature request to apple. P.S I've upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This link has a wonderful tutorial on how to make a custom based UIImagePickerController to select multiple images.

http://www.icodeblog.com/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/

Answer (score 3):

uiimagepicker only choose one image from photo library so use  ELCImagePickerController in palce of uiimagepickercontroller and  ELCImagePickerController is woking correct ... I m test this in my Photo collage App